Connection times out for putty or openssh connection to ec2 instance (Linux) from Windows machine
I am unable to connect to my linux ec2 instance via putty or openssh from my windows machine. My instnce is on a public subnet, inbound rule is attached to security group to allow all traffic to port 22. Connection problem seems to be from my PC's side. I have inbound rule added to firewall for port 22, openssh is up and running on pc, but port 22 seems to still be closed. I do not have a config file in my .ssh folder. Could I add one to solve this issue? What else can I try? Both openssh and putty connections time out. I tried telneting from port 22 and it doesn't work either, with connection failed error. I am on my home internet network. IGW is also added to ec2 subnet
